# Use variable in a patchesJson6902 of a kustomization.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I would like to set the `name` field in a `Namespace` resource and also replace the `namespace` field in a `Deployment` resource with the same value, for example `my-namespace`.

Here is `kustomization.json`:

```
namespace: <NAMESPACE>
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
patchesJson6902:
- patch: |-
    - op: replace
      path: /metadata/name
      value: <NAMESPACE>
  target:
    kind: Namespace
    name: system
    version: v1
resources:
- manager.yaml
```

and `manager.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  labels:
    control-plane: controller-manager
  name: system
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: controller-manager
  namespace: system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      control-plane: controller-manager
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        control-plane: controller-manager
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /manager
        args:
        - --enable-leader-election
        image: controller:latest
        name: manager
```

I tried using `kustomize edit set namespace my-namespace && kustomize build`, but it only changes the `namespace` field in the `Deployment` object.

Is there a way to change both field without using `sed`, in 'pure' `kustomize` and without having to change manually  value in `kustomization.json`?

Comment: Which kustomize version are you using?

Comment: ```kustomize version
{Version:kustomize/v3.8.4 GitCommit:8285af8cf11c0b202be533e02b88e114ad61c1a9 BuildDate:2020-09-19T15:39:21Z GoOs:linux GoArch:amd64}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there a way to change both field without using `sed`, in 'pure' `kustomize` and without having to change manually value in `kustomization.json`?**

I managed to achieve somewhat similar with the following configuration:

```yaml
kustomization.yaml

apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: my-namespace
resources:
- deployment.yaml
```

```yaml
depyloment.yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.14.2
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

And here is the output of the command that you used:

```sh
➜  kustomize kustomize edit set namespace my-namespace7 && kustomize build .
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: my-namespace7
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: my-namespace7
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.14.2
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

What is happening here is that once you set the `namespace` globally in `kustomization.yaml` it will apply it to your targets which looks to me that looks an easier way to achieve what you want.

I cannot test your config without `manager_patch.yaml` content. If you wish to go with your way further you will have update the question with the file content.

Comment: Thanks! you answer works fine with `kustomize` v3 and v4. My problem was that I was using an old version build from source in some place.